# return results based on multiple record criteria

Tags: sql

I need to return invoices from a transaction list that have both product A and product B on it

example of the table

```
prod_code | invoice
 apple    |  100
 banana   |  100
 orange   |  100
 apple    |  101
 kiwi     |  101
 grape    |  101
 apple    |  102
 banana   |  102
 grape    |  102
```

I need to input 2 products and it must list the invoice numbers that have both products.
If i input apple and banana it must return 100 and 102
If i input apple and grape it returns 101 and 102

It seems like it should be very simple but for the life of me i cant think on how to do this.

SOLVED

Ok i solved my own question. Dont know why i didnt think of it earlier. As i thought it was pretty simple.

```
select invoice from transaction where prod_code="apple" and invoice in (select invoice from transaction where prod_code="banana")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  invoice
FROM
  transactions
WHERE
  prod_code IN ('apple', 'banana')
GROUP BY
  invoice
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT prod_code) = 2
```

Note, however, that this is not a fast query, and with the structure that you have it's not easy to make significant performance gains.

By its nature the first step must by `find all invoices with 'apple' <OR> 'banana'` and only after that to filter to invoices that have both.

An alternative is...

```
SELECT
  t_apple.invoice
FROM
  transactions     AS t_apple
INNER JOIN
  transactions     AS t_banana
    ON t_apple.invoice = t_banana.invoice
WHERE
      t_apple.prod_code  = 'apple'
  AND t_banana.prod_code = 'banana'
```

But that's less simple to generalise to `n` prod_codes.

Comment: @LispWarez - Both of these queries are quite common contructs.  Could you elaborate on `didnt work`?  I'm sure we can make this work for you, I use both all of the time...